# How to animate a social sharing buttons div on mouseover using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am trying to make social button animation for my website,

Take this as an example animation of sharing round div on top right side : http://www.dubbelfrisss.nl

How can I make this type of mouse hover animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can check here DEMOs http://tympanus.net/Development/IconHoverEffects/

Website http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/30/simple-icon-hover-effects/

Comment: if i want to animate through jquery, how can i do that?

Comment: you can animate with css styles with jquery .animate(), check here http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: :( i am 0 for jquery...

Comment: first, you check here, download and play around ? http://webcssjquery.net/2012/12/13/googleplus-circle-animation-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

draw a cicle with css. you can also use css3 instead of jquery to animate it, if u dont want to support old browsers. if you want to make it with jquery read about set width/heigt and maybe use animate function. learn jquery. 
here an examplke with css3

```
div.test {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    background: red;
}

div.test:hover {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    background: red;
}
```